# Are late instance fields initialized Lazily in the Constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand that `late` initializers, i.e. declarations that directly have the initializing assignment, are executed lazily:

```dart
class Foo {
  late final word = calculateWord(); // Will be initialized lazily.
  late final sentence; // Will not be initialized lazily.

  void init() {
    sentence = calculateSentence(); // This is immediately executed, i.e. before sentence is accessed.
  }
}
```

However, what I am wondering is how that behavior maps to constructors. I would assume that the variable **is lazily initialized** in constructors because the instance fields are then assigned at the same time as ones that have their initializer directly with the assignment.

However, I would also assume that the *constructor body* does **not lazily** initialize `late` instance fields.

---

So which of the following members are lazily initialized if any?

```dart
class Baz {
  Baz(
    // Implicit assignment by the caller.
    this.assignmentInConstructor,
  ) : assignmentInInitializerList = calculate() {
    assignmentInConstructorBody = calculate();
  }


  late final int assignmentInConstructor; // I expect this to be lazily initialized.

  late final int assignmentInInitializerList; // I expect this to also be lazily initialized.

  late final int assignmentInConstructorBody; // I expect this to not be lazily initialized.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## None are lazy

A `late` modified field is only ever lazy when the assignment happens *with the declaration*.

This also means that the following is true:

```dart
void main() {
  late final value1 = calculate(); // This is initialized lazily.

  late final value2;value2 = calculate(); // This is not initialized lazily.
}
```

Only by adding `;value2`, I separated the assignment from the declaration, which makes it not lazy anymore.

### Instance fields

Consequently, all instance fields that are initialized anywhere in the constructor are **not lazily initialized**. They are instead initialized before they are accessed.

## Demo

```dart
void main() {
  // Construct the object first.
  final baz = Baz(calculate('assignmentInConstructor'));

  // Call access to access the late variables and initialize them if they are lazy.
  baz.access();
}

class Baz {
  Baz(
    // Implicit assignment by the caller.
    this.assignmentInConstructor,
  ) : assignmentInInitializerList = calculate('assignmentInInitializerList') {
    assignmentInConstructorBody = calculate('assignmentInConstructorBody');
  }

  late final int
      assignmentInConstructor; // I expect this to be lazily initialized.

  late final int
      assignmentInInitializerList; // I expect this to also be lazily initialized.

  late final int
      assignmentInConstructorBody; // I expect this to not be lazily initialized.

  void access() {
    print('access');
    print('$assignmentInConstructor'
        '$assignmentInInitializerList'
        '$assignmentInConstructorBody');
  }
}

int calculate(String message) {
  print('calcuate $message');
  return 0;
}
```

Executing `main` yields the following output:

```
calcuate assignmentInConstructor
calcuate assignmentInInitializerList
calcuate assignmentInConstructorBody
access
000
```

This means that *all three instance fields*, no matter where in the constructor they are initialized, are *not lazily initialized*. They are all calculated before they are accessed.

You can try it yourself in [this DartPad demo](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/a5b1ae1e3cbc2a389b713f49fd910a0f).